# PHP Mail sending file with html instead of php (Gmail)

Tags: php, html, email, attachment

I've been using this script for about 2 months and everything was working properly.
Today I was adding new functionalities related to sending an email and I noticed that the emails sent to gmail were having some problems, but only on gmail.
Instead of receiving a regular message (text/html) I receive a file named "no name.html" with the message sent.

Here's my code:

```
$from = "My name <example@gmail.com>";
$email = "dest@gmail.com"
$to = "";
$subject = "Subject Here";
$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$username = "example@gmail.com";
$password = "passwordhere";
$headers = "";
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => $host,
                            'auth' => true,
                            'username' => $username,
                            'password' => $password));

$body = "<div>Hello World</div>";                     
$to = "<" . $email . ">";
$headers = array('From' => $from,
                            'To' => $to,
                            'Subject' => $subject,
                            "MIME-Version" => "1.0",
                            "Content-Type" => "text/html charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"",
                            "Content-Transfer-Encoding" => "8bit");
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" 
 content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\"></head><body>" . $body . "</body></html>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't if it is the reason of your problem, but:

In your header, you have a charset ISO:

```
"Content-Type" => "text/html charset=\"ISO-8859-1\""
```

And in the html content, UTF-8 :

```
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\">
```

Comment: to send a mail, you should not use an array for the header but a string: use implode("/r/n",$headers) instead of $headers

Comment: OK (i confuse with the php mail function wich requires a string). In your code you don't mention the smtp port, maybe the default port is not correct for gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I used phpmailer instead and now it's working fine.